# Why there are no fields in cleaned_data?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have form:

```
class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    oldpassword = forms.CharField(
        min_length=5,
        label=_('Old password'),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        min_length=5,
        label=_('Password'),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        min_length=5,
        label=_('Retype'),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
    )

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('The new passwords must be the same'))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data
```

And if I type to all fields I get POST:

```
{u'password1': [u'ewrtrwetwe'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'2gEAqLjaKC5NgMZrE6Brd9p3vThUC10w'], u'oldpassword': [u'wertwertwet'], u'password2': [u'tewrtwertwert']}
```

and cleaned_data:

```
{'password1': u'ewrtrwetwe', 'password2': u'tewrtwertwert', 'oldpassword': u'wertwertwet'}
```

But if I type the same text in password1 and password2 input I get POST:

```
{u'password1': [u'1234'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'2gEAqLjaKC5NgMZrE6Brd9p3vThUC10w'], u'oldpassword': [u'wertwertwet'], u'password2': [u'1234']}
```

and cleaned_data:

```
{'oldpassword': u'wertwertwet'}
```

and I get an error:

```
if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
KeyError: 'password1'
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the `cleaned_data` in your `clean()` method. You need to write it more like this:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ChangePasswordtForm, self).clean()
    # Do things
    return cleaned_data
```

Also, you should always `return cleaned_data`, even if you `raise ValidationError` (no longer true for django 1.7+)